# Sort a List in which each element contains 2 Values

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a text file that contains Values in this Format: `Time|ID`:

```
180|1
60 |2
120|3
```

Now I want to sort them by Time. The Output also should be:

```
60 |2
120|3
180|1
```

How can I solve this problem? With this:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.txt";

List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

list.Sort();

for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

I got no success ...

Comment: @Mong: tags exist to explain what the question is _about_. Do not add tags just because some aspect is mentioned. This question is in no way _about_ [tag:string], so your edit to add that tag was completely inappropriate and has been rolled back.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "tags exist to explain what the question is about." I actually thought that this question is about sorting strings from a file. That is why I added the tag. But if you think that this " question is in no way about string" then I will not protest. In the end the question is actually about sorting integers that come as a string from a file.

Comment: @Mong: the user is not having any trouble at all with the string values. Nor even the integer values. Thus, the question is not _about_ either of those things. And frankly, you are abusing Stack Overflow when you spam the tags like that, because it makes it that much harder to find the questions and answers that are legitimately _about_ e.g. strings, i.e. the actual handling and manipulation of string objects, as opposed to data structures that simply happen to have string objects within them.

Comment: @Mong: and, I notice that while you have edited a large number of question tags recently, those edits are almost all done only to questions where you've posted an answer. This suggests strongly that your motives are selfishly designed simply to attempt to increase traffic to your own answers. Again, this is an abuse of the Stack Overflow community, and done at the expense of users who are trying to find information that's actually useful to them.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you for your comments. You surely have some valid points in your argumentation. I will be more carefull in the future when tagging questions. "those edits are almost all done only to questions where you've posted an answer. " that is true, I found some questions in my history of answers that were poorly tagged (in my point of view) so I started to browse through the answers looking whether some of the questions aspects were not covered by the appropriate tags. This was definetely **not** "designed simply to attempt to increase traffic to your own answers".

Comment: @PeterDuniho  If my behaviour is accounted as an abuse, I appologize deeply and gladly remove the tags that I added over the last 2 days, and stop browsing the history of my answers. It was never my intent to abuse this community. seriously.

Comment: @Mong: it is impossible for me to know what your motives are, even if you claim only good intentions. All I can tell you is what the _appearance_ is. However, for sure you are harming the community when you apply tags too broadly. That's objectively true. It would be great if you would be more careful about adding tags to questions, and make _very certain_ any tag you add really does describe what the question is _about_, i.e. is the very thing that the user asking the question needs help with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196428/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-peter-duniho).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can understand that it appears this way. Thank you for the heuristic for adding tags to questions
That in fact was my leading heuristic. But apparently I overdid it.
I will be more carefully in future.
Apparently you removed the most tags that I added already.
But I have to say that sometimes it is difficult to decide when the question bears the title "How to format this string to DateTime in .NET" that this question is not about strings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 steps are necessary to do the job:

1) split by the separator

2) convert to `int` because in a string comparison a 6 comes after a 1 or 10

3) use [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) to sort your collection

Here is a linq solution in one line doing all 3 steps:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('|')[0])).ToList();
```

Explanation

`x =>` lambda expression, x denotes a single element in your list
`x.Split('|')[0]` splits each string and takes only the first part of it (time)
`Convert.ToInt32(..` converts the time into a number so that the ordering will be done in the way you desire

`list.OrderBy(` sorts your collection

**EDIT:**

Just to understand why you got the result in the first place here is an example of comparison of numbers in string representation using the [CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
int res = "6".CompareTo("10");
```

res will have the value of `1` (meaning that 6 is larger than 10 or 6 follows 10)

According to the documentation->remarks:

> The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations.

Comment: @impidimpi you are very welcome. Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should parse each line of the file content and get values as numbers.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path");

//                         ID, time
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

// Processing each line of the file content
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] splitted = line.Split('|');

    int time = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[0]);
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(splitted[1]);

    // Key = ID, Value = Time
    dict.Add(ID, time);
}

var orderedListByID = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
var orderedListByTime = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Note that I use your `ID` reference as `Key` of dictionary assuming that `ID` should be unique.

**Short code version**

```
//                                                                      Key = ID                    Value = Time
var orderedListByID = lines.Select(x => x.Split('|')).ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[1]), x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0])).OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
var orderedListByTime = lines.Select(x => x.Split('|')).ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[1]), x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0])).OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert them to numbers first. Sorting by string won't give you meaningful results.

```
times = list.Select(l => l.Split('|')[0]).Select(Int32.Parse);
ids   = list.Select(l => l.Split('|')[1]).Select(Int32.Parse);

pairs = times.Zip(ids, (t, id) => new{Time = t, Id = id})
             .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, this is my Solution:

```
    var path = @"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.txt";

    List<string> list = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
    list = list.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('|')[0])).ToList();

    for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Collections;   
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <LineItem> myList = new ArrayList<LineItem>();     
   myList.add(LineItem.getLineItem(500, 30));    
   myList.add(LineItem.getLineItem(300, 20));    
   myList.add(LineItem.getLineItem(900, 100));  
   System.out.println(myList);

  Collections.sort(myList);

  System.out.println("list after sort");

  System.out.println(myList);



    }

}


class LineItem  implements Comparable<LineItem>{
    int time;
    int id ;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ""+ time + "|"+ id  + "  ";
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(LineItem o) {
        return this.time-o.time;
    } 

    public static LineItem getLineItem( int time, int id ){
        LineItem l = new LineItem();
        l.time=time;
        l.id=id;
        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like java... did you miss the C# tag?